# Logstash upper case mapping names

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've tried to replace my old import to logstash. Everything works fine but logstash will always push the new data with lowercase property names.

Is there a way to push the data via logstash with uppercase property names into my elastic search?

*...otherwise I have to rewrite some applications. :(*

**SAMPLE**

```
My indexed document.
{
 "ID": 1,
 "NAME": "DEMO" 
}

Logstash index document
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "DEMO" 
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to use the rename option of the [mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-rename).

Comment: Wow perfect it works with the following code:
`filter {
  mutate {
    # Renames the 'HOSTORIP' field to 'client_ip'
    rename => { "HOSTORIP" => "client_ip" }
  }
}`